# Setting instance variables in Action Mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am wondering what is a clean and conventional way for setting instance variables in Mailers?  Currently, I have re-defined the `initialize` method in `Mailer` and subsequently overwrite certain instance variables when needed in any mailers that inherit from `Mailer`.

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  attr_reader :ivar

  def initialize
    super
    @ivar = :blah
    ...
  end
end
```

This only seems weird to me because `new` is a private method for mailers.  For example, if I were to try to retrieve these in the rails console, I need to do the following:

```
mailer = Mailer.send(:new)
mailer.ivar
```

I have also considered adding them to the `default` hash like so:

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default ivar: :blah,
  ...
end
```

The only problem being that I need to create a method like this to retrieve the ivars:

```
def default_getter(ivar)
  self.class.default[ivar]
end
```

Neither way seems particularly clean to me.  I've considered using class variables, but I'm wondering if someone could suggest a cleaner way.  Thanks.

Comment: Either way seems clean to me, FWIW.

Comment: Ah, so I would actually incur an error if I ran this because I left off the arguments on initialize: (method_name, *args).

Comment: I'll leave this open in case anyone provides a cleaner answer.  I ended up using the `initialize`, but I had to call `super` AFTER ivar assignment or else the ivars do not get assigned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a little bit late...

You can use before_action callbacks

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks