# Setting instance variables in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, instance-variables

I have around 30 mailer methods where I'm passing the user as an argument. Since I need access to the @user variable in the view, I'm having to set this instance variable in every mailer method, for example, send_x_email(user).

Normally this would be done in an initialize method, but I've read that mailers act a bit differently. Additionally, some of the methods take a different number of arguments (one just takes user, the other takes user and message).

I've investigated before_action callbacks and looked at this post

[Setting instance variables in Action Mailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236674/setting-instance-variables-in-action-mailer)

...but I'm still stuck.

I would appreciate any thoughts on how to simplify things and remove @user = user from the 30 or so methods in the mailer class. Cheers!

```
class ReminderSender < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_commands_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email,
         subject: "All Commands",
         from: "<commands@#{ENV['DOMAIN']}>")
  end

  def send_attachment_warning(user, message)
    @user = user
    @message = message
    mail(to: @user.email,
         subject: "Attachment Warning",
         from: "<attachments@#{ENV['DOMAIN']}>")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try defining a 'mail' method in your class and declaring an instance variable there e.g.

```
class YouMailer

  def send_email(user, message)
    subject = 'something'
    body = message

    mail(user, {subject: subject, body: body}})
  end

  def mail(user, options={})
    @user = user
    mail_options = {to: @user.email}.merge(options)

    super(mail_options)
  end
end
```

But you might need to specify the 'template_path' and 'template_name' options with that strategy.

My suggestion would be to keep things as they are. Having "@user = user" in all of your mailer methods out of necessity isn't bad.

Comment: Agree re: setting `@user` in all the methods.  You can actually think of mailer methods as analogous to controller actions.  In a controller action you don't think twice about setting instance variables for each method, because you know that a new controller instance is created for each request and exactly one action is ever called.